# Order of result list in ListUtils.intersection

Tags: java, algorithm, apache-commons

I am trying to find the intersection between two lists. I did some tests with Apache Commons ListUtils.intersection and empirically found that elements in the result are returned in the second list order.

```
ListUtils.intersection(asList(1,2,3,4),asList(3,1,2,6,7)

=[3, 1, 2]
```

Is this behavior specified to be consistent in the future? I couldn't find any reference.

Comment: If you didn't find any reference, then you cannot depend on it. It could change in the future, or in a different JVM, or on the kind of lists being used, and on other things I haven't thought of. Saying "elements ... are always returned in the second list order." is a misleading way of thinking about it; if instead you say "I ran N tests and those always returned results in the second list order.", your question almost answers itself. You didn't try all combinations of lists, or all sizes of lists, or all JVMs, etc.

Comment: @AlexFung jjjaaavvvaaa

Comment: @arcy You are right, I edited the question to remove the 'always'

Comment: @jesantana - Always should stand good in your example, since list 2 is bigger than list 1. So the list 2 order will be preserved in the result. Please see my answer for more clarity

Answer (score 1):

The trick lies in the implementation of `org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils.intersection`

For the iteration of lists bigger list is taken, in your case list 2 is bigger than list 1 and hence you are getting the results always from list 2.

The behavior is

> If list 2 is having more elements or equal number of elements to list
>   1 then the result order will be in the list 2 order.
>
> If list 1 is having more elements than list 2 then the result order
>   will be in the list 1 order.

Code snippet of `org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils.intersection` which does this work

```
public static <E> List<E> intersection(final List<? extends E> list1, final List<? extends E> list2) {

final List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();
    List<? extends E> smaller = list1;
    List<? extends E> larger = list2;
    if (list1.size() > list2.size()) {
        smaller = list2;
        larger = list1;
    }

    final HashSet<E> hashSet = new HashSet<E>(smaller);

    for (final E e : larger) {
        if (hashSet.contains(e)) {
            result.add(e);
            hashSet.remove(e);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Full source code of List Utils is available here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html

Comment: Is this part of the contract of the operation? Reading the source code to figure out internals and then depending on what you figure out means that, if anyone ever changes that implementation, or you use a set of code that satisfies Java contracts and constraints but does not implement things the same way, your code could break. Whose fault would you think that was?

Comment: @arcy - Apache is a standard set of library and the chance of getting the implementation changed is very rare. In this case we always need to iterate till we reach the last element of larger list, so I believe the implementation should not change. Java Doc provided for the intersection method says about the parameters and the return types. The more detail on why the behavior of bigger list order is obtained in the result I got it when I went in and see the code only, I could not find this information in any documentation or blogs

Comment: My point is that it is poor engineering to DEPEND on the implementation, whether YOU think it is likely to change or not. That is the whole point of interfaces and contracts between software components. If you depend on a particular order, and the contract for your library does not include the order, then it is poor engineering to go look 'under the covers' and say, "Oh, see, it does that and I do not see that it will change." Even if it isn't likely to, or isn't likely to as long as you're responsible for the maintenance.